# is static const in C++ same as const in C?

Tags: c++, c, static, constants

In C header file:

```
const int AvarInC = 1;
```

Now in C++ file:

```
class Cpp
{
   public:

   static const int PublicAvar = 1;

   private:

   static const int Avar = 1;
};
```

while i have: 
const int AvarInC = 1; in my C headers
OR 
static const int AvarInC = 1; in my C headers.

Will it be the same thing? Is the first one without keyword static, implicitly static?

Comment: The variable `Avar` cannot be accessed from outside the scope of `Cpp`. `PublicAvar` can be accessed from anywhere as `Cpp::PublicAvar`.

Comment: Thanks Bart van Nierop. You are right about PublicAvar. But i think we should have all our variables in Private scope. So i asked it.

Comment: BTW, `class Cpp` makes me shiver. I hope this is a contrived example, not your way of mimicking Java, attempting to put your `main()` inside a class...

Comment: This is such an ambiguous question. It will be hard to answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is similar.  Of course, you can use the C way in C++ as well.

But the specific C++ way (a class member) also differs in visibility and scope.  Only code that is part of class `Cpp` (or a friend) can access `Avar`.  The `PublicAvar` is somewhere in between; anyone can access it, but they need to refer to it as `Cpp.PublicAvar`.

The keyword `static` has two distinct meanings in C++.  Sometimes it means the storage class (as in your example) - that is, "this is not a per-instance member".  In this respect, a variable which is not a member of a class at all is obviously static without having to declare that.

Other times, `static` may refer to link-time visibility.  A static symbol is only valid inside its own compilation unit.  That's the original C meaning.  It does not come into your example especially because we are assuming that your code goes in a header file, and is therefore present in multiple compilation units.  Marking a non-member variable as `static` would result in a number of copies of the variable in the program (one per compilation unit) which would not hurt for a `const` variable, but generally it could lead to very confusing program behavior.

Comment: while i have: const int AvarInC = 1; OR static const int AvarInC = 1; in my C headers. Will it be the same thing? Is the first one without keyword static, implicitly static?

Comment: @learningfellow: Please read the linked possible duplicate. No, `static` is never implicit, and having a `static` variable in a C header is almost certainly **not** what you want.

Comment: tried to expand the answer to better cover the last two comments

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, no they aren't quite the same. Since you are putting the C one in a header file, I'm assuming it will be a global constant, therefore there will really only be one copy of it anyways. It won't need to be recreated each time (since that what `static` will do.

However, the one in the C++ file is inside a class and static, so every time that class is instantiated into an object all instances will share the same copy of the `PublicAvar` variable and it won't get recreated with each object.

Though, I have a feeling you knew what `static` does. So technically no, they don't do the same thing and aren't the same thing...but they do act similarly.

I'm not an expert, so I could be wrong but I believe this is right. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

"The same" is quite ambiguous. Both will be treated as compile-time constant. You can (should) not change them at runtime and the compiler can decide to use this information to optimize your code.

Comment: I think this is the first time I've come across the term "compile-time variable" for a constant. It's certainly correct in a way, but... weird. Not my downvote, though.

Comment: Changed it to "compile-time constant". It should indicate that the compiler knows the value of the constant. In opposite to `const int a = foo();` (and foo reads a file) where the value is not known at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

No, they are not `same`. They are both variables are initialized at compile time. But `static` variable can be accessed without creating any `object` of a `class`, but `non static` variable only exists within an object. i.e, the `static` variable takes common space in the memory for any number of objects created for it, but not in case of the other one.